# I need 2 formats needed in an excel spreadsheet column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am not using .NET only excel.
1. I have a column of values from 1 - 10.
examples:

```
2,00
2,34
6,30
7,00
```

(Comas because I live in Spain)
2. I don't want the whole numbers to show decimal points.
ie: I need

```
2
2,34
6,30
7
```

Answer (score 0):

What is selected when you right click and go to `Format Cells...`?

I suspect it is a `Number` formatting, where the number of decimals must be specified. If you select `General`, this should get rid of zeros after the last non-zero significant figure.

Bear in mind this will mean you have:

```
2
2,34
6,3     <---- no zero here
7
```

Alternatively you could format each cell with your specifications.

Comment: Hi. You were right at first so 6,00 becomes 6. BUT now I have numbers like 6,6473829304 instead of 6,65. How do I round those down to two decimal points.

Comment: Use the `ROUND` function ;-). [MSDN page here](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/ROUND-function-c018c5d8-40fb-4053-90b1-b3e7f61a213c)

Answer (score 0):

You *could* do this with conditional formatting. Set the cell format to `General` and then set the conditional format to override that formatting if the cell is not a whole number:

Create a rule that has the formula (assuming the top left cell in question is `A1`)

```
=IF(A1<>INT(A1),TRUE,FALSE)
```

With that rule, set the conditional format to `Number` with 2 decimal places.